# How to wake screen from service properly?

Tags: android

I have IntentService where am I creating an notification. I want screen to turn on after the notification is created. How could i do that right since `PowerManager.WakeLock screenOn = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "example");` is depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was same as yours but Below code worked for me correctly..

Make a class WakeLocaker.java in your package

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

and call the following lines code in **`private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()`** presents in your activity

Then Call the release lock method

```
// Releasing wake lock
WakeLocker.release();
```

Don't forget to add permission in your menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

This code credit is totally belongs to 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Yeah, i know this. But `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is depreciated. I thought, there is some better way to do it.

Comment: Hey David I found this on [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) that   

This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.

May be this would help you. I am not sure

Comment: at the time of IntentService excution is there any UI/Activity of you app is visible to user or not? if visible then you can put FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in that activity or in that screen xml android:keepScreenOn = "true" if not then fire a broadcast for this FLAG. Let me know your view so that these situation work or not so that I can do more digging find another way.